# Criando arquivos em Haskell

Tags: arquivo, stream-de-arquivos, haskell

Eu queria gravar a saída do meu programa direto em um arquivo. 
Quando eu executasse o código, automaticamente gerava um arquivo com as saídas deste código ao invés de imprimi-las na tela.

Um exemplo simples:

```
func =  do
writeFile "file.txt" show(calc)
calc = do return (1+1)
```

Nem sei se isso é possível. Sou iniciante em Haskell e ainda não sei como utilizar arquivos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve usar a função [writeFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:writeFile) pra sobrescrever ou [appendFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:appendFile) para adicionar ao final, descritas na [seção 7.1 do Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/io-13.html).

Corrigindo seu exemplo (e explicitando os tipos):

```
func :: IO ()
func = writeFile "file.txt" (show calc)

calc :: Integer
calc = 1 + 1
```

### Explicação

Ao escrever `writeFile "file.txt" show(calc)`, você está chamando `writeFile` com 3 argumentos: `"file.txt"`, a função `show`, e o resultado de `calc`.  A versão acima descreve o comportamento correto:

```
writeFile "file.txt" (show calc)
```

#### Sobre `calc`

`return` em Haskell tem um significado diferente da maioria das linguagens.  Não significa retorne o valor como resultado da função, mas sim, "[injetar um valor em um tipo monádico](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:return)".  Para "retornar" um valor como em uma linguagem convêncional, simplesmente escreva o valor que quer retornar:

```
calc = 1 + 1
```

Comment: +1 por apontar que `return` não tem nada a ver com o `return` de linguagens imperativas. Só acho que vale a pena acrescentar que o que o `return` em Haskell faz é "colocar determinado valor dentro de um Contexto mínimo", que são os tais `monads`. Exemplo: quando você está lidando com Listas, o menor contexto default é a lista vazia `[]`, então um `return 1 :: [Int]` vai lhe retornar `[1]` (o seu valor encapsulado no Contexto de uma lista de Int). Sim, é a mesma coisa que você falou @Rudy, mas talvez seja mais claro para algumas pessoas (eu incluso).

Answer (score 0):

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do 

       dado <- getLine
       outh <- openFile "saida.txt" WriteMode

       hPutStr outh (map toUpper dado)

       hClose outh
```